# Can't get rid of scratch buffer at startup for Emacs 26.3

Tags: init-file, window, emacsclient, scratch

I am using GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2019-08-29.
In my `.emacs` I specifically asked not to show the startup screen or buffer `*scratch*`:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(inhibit-startup-screen t)
 '(initial-buffer-choice nil))
```

However, whenever I open a file with `emacs` (or `runemacs`), the window is split in half, showing both the `*scratch*` buffer and the file I opened. How do I get rid of showing the `*scratch*` buffer when I start Emacs?

Comment: How are you opening a file?

Comment: Every possible ways I can think of: 1) emacs filename 2) runemacs filename 3) right click on the file and sendto "runemacs" and "emacs" etc... all behave the same.

Answer (score 3):

I battled with this phenomenon for years and discovered that Emacs automatically recreates a scratch buffer if there are no other buffers.  In addition, Emacs creates a scratch buffer on startup.  There are a variety of factors that affect how buffers are displayed on startup, including, but not limited to the hard coded (baked-in) `startup.el`.  The `startup.el` file cannot be changed without rebuilding Emacs subsequent thereto so that those changes can be incorporated into the build itself.  People who use the popular `desktop.el` library to restore a previous layout are necessarily using the `after-init-hook` to restore the prior session -- so that can affect what buffer is displayed when Emacs starts.  I would suggest using the `emacs-startup-hook`, which runs later than the `after-init-hook`, to either bury the scratch buffer or kill it.  Another idea that I just thought of, but haven't tested, is to set the `initial-major-mode` variable to the value of a custom function that deals with how you wish to handle that buffer -- but the O.P. may need to experiment with when that setting gets taken into consideration during startup.  There are other factors to consider such as newer versions of Emacs add support for an `early-init.el` file where settings can be stored.  Here is an example utilizing the `emacs-startup-hook`:

```lisp
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook (lambda ()
                                (when (get-buffer-window "*scratch*")
                                  (bury-buffer "*scratch*"))))
```

Feel free to play around with that example and customize it to suit your needs; e.g., `(kill-buffer "*scratch*")` instead of burying it, then put your preferred buffer in its place with `set-window-buffer` to set the desired buffer in the desired window ... the sky is the limit.

Here is another example using the `emacs-startup-hook` that kills the `*scratch*` buffer if it exists even if it is not presently displayed in a window:

```lisp
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook (lambda ()
                                (when (get-buffer "*scratch*")
                                  (kill-buffer "*scratch*"))))
```

Comment: Thanks. But that doesn't make sense that emacs insists on creating a new buffer because it's opening an existing file. 

I tried your suggestions, that bury-buffer didn't work, but the kill-buffer worked. However, now I have that opened file in a split window because the the scratch buffer was killed and it's replaced with the opened file.

Another strange thing is that I have another pc running windows 10, and the same .emacs setting and the other one doesn't have this problem.

Comment: In terms of understanding when Emacs creates a `*scratch*` buffer, there are two places you can look to study the code:  (1) `M-x find-library RET startup RET` and then word-search that Lisp library for all of the occurrences of `(get-buffer-create "*scratch*")` -- see which, if any, apply to your use-case.  (2) Have a look at the source code used to build Emacs at the function `init_buffer_once` at the line that states:  `Fset_buffer (Fget_buffer_create (build_pure_c_string ("*scratch*")))` -- `init_buffer_once` is called by the function `main` in `emacs.c`.  Feel free to study the code more.

Comment: I would suggest one of two approaches to your use-case:  (1) use `delete-window` to delete whichever window you don't want being sure to test first for whether more than one window exists and the buffers that are being displayed in the windows; (2) use `delete-other-windows` ensuring that you have focus in the window that you want to keep.  `delete-window` has an optional argument for a specific window.  You might try placing some messages in the example function in the answer and see how many windows are visible when the `emacs-startup-hook` runs, and what is displayed in the window(s).

Comment: As an addendum to the second comment underneath this answer, I see a few other calls to creating the `*scratch*` buffer in the C source code using `Fget_buffer_create (scratch)` ... the function `init_buffer`, the function `other_buffer` (aka `other-buffer`), and the function `other_buffer_safely`.  There may be other references in the C source code where the `*scratch*` buffer gets created ... I've only done some minimal grepping of the Emacs 26.3 source code to post the comments herein and hereinabove.

Comment: Yes, instead of using bury-buffer or kill-buffer, use delete-window-on worked! Thanks! 
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook (lambda ()
                                (when (get-buffer "*scratch*")
                                  (delete-windows-on "*scratch*"))))

Answer (score 0):

Using [`window-buffer-change-functions`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Hooks.html#index-window_002dbuffer_002dchange_002dfunctions) I finally got rid of `*scratch*`.

```lisp
(defun buffer-change-hook (frame)
  (unless (string-equal (buffer-name (current-buffer)) "*scratch*")
      (kill-buffer "*scratch*")
    )
  )

(add-hook 'window-buffer-change-functions 'buffer-change-hook)
```